# Code "beautifier" in Clojure

Tags: performance, clojure

I've recently made a plugin that "beautifies" code. What it does is lump all the semicolons and curly braces to one side of the program, thus making the code "whitespace-sensitive", and therefore "beautiful".

Here is the code:

```clj
(ns beautifier.core
  (:require [clojure.string :as s]
            [clojure.java.io :as io])
  (:gen-class))

;;; Private variables/functions

;; Atom to define the gap between special characters
;; and rest of code
(def ^:private gap (atom 1))

;; Gets index of first item that satisfies pred:
;;    (first-index-of even? [1 2 3])
;; => 1
(defn ^:private first-index-of [pred coll]
  (loop [a 0]
    (cond
      (= a (count coll)) nil
      (pred (nth coll a)) a
      :else (recur (inc a)))))

;; Right-pads a string until it is greater than or
;; equal to a given length:
;;    (right-pad "abcd" 7)
;; => "abcd   "
(defn ^:private right-pad [string length]
  (loop [new-str string]
    (if (>= (count new-str) length) new-str
      (recur (str new-str " ")))))

;;; Public functions

;; Set the gap between the longest line and the
;; special characters
(defn set-gap [n]
  (if (< n 1)
    (throw (Exception. "Invalid gap size!"))
    (reset! gap n)))

;; Function that takes a list of lines as input,
;; and returns beautified code as output.
(defn beautify [lines]
  ;; Main loop
  (loop [stripped []
        endings []
        ind 0]
    (if (= ind (count lines))
      ;; Spits out content to the output file
      ;; when the loop is finished.
      (apply str
        ;; Defines new list, in which all the lines have whitespace
        ;; at the front taken into account.
        (let [new-stripped
              (for [a (range (count stripped))]
                (let [line (nth lines (first (nth stripped a)))
                      start-spaces
                      (subs line 0
                        (first-index-of
                          #(not= \space %)
                          line))]
                  (str start-spaces (second (nth stripped a)))))]
          (println new-stripped)
          (for [b (range (count new-stripped))]
            ;; Right-pads string.
            (str
              (right-pad (nth new-stripped b) (+ @gap (apply max (map count new-stripped))))
              (nth endings b)
              "\n"))))
      ;; Separates special characters from the body at
      ;; the beginning and end
      (let [line-no-ws (s/trim (nth lines ind))
            previous
            (let [f-index
                  (first-index-of
                    #(not (some #{%} "{};"))
                    line-no-ws)]
              (subs line-no-ws 0
                (if (nil? f-index) (count line-no-ws) f-index)))
            next
            (if (= previous line-no-ws) ""
              (subs line-no-ws
                (- (count line-no-ws)
                  (first-index-of
                    #(not (some #{%} "{};"))
                  (reverse line-no-ws)))))
            stripped-line
            (s/trim
              (subs line-no-ws
                (count previous) (- (count line-no-ws) (count next))))]
        ;; Append removed characters at the start to the end of
        ;; the next line, and place removed characters at the end
        ;; to the start of the next line.
        (if (= stripped-line "")
          (recur
            stripped
            (assoc endings
              (dec (count endings)) (str (last endings) previous))
            (inc ind))
          (recur
            (conj stripped [ind stripped-line])
            (let [new-endings (conj endings next)]
              (if (not= previous "")
                (assoc new-endings
                  (- (count new-endings) 2)
                  (str (nth new-endings (- (count new-endings) 2)) previous))
                new-endings))
            (inc ind)))))))

;; Function that beautifies a file, takes a file directory
;; as both input and output.
(defn beautify-file [in-file out-file]
  (let [lines
        (with-open [reader (io/reader in-file)]
          (doall (line-seq reader)))]
    (spit out-file
      (beautify lines))))

;; Main function
(defn -main [& args]
  (set-gap 10)
  (beautify-file "resources/test.java" "resources/beautiful.java"))
```

Is there any improvements or optimisations I can achieve in Clojure, in terms of accessibility and readability, as well as speed?

The main area that I don't like about this is the ridiculous size of the `beautify` function, which is essentially half the actual program. I've probably missed some optimisations here and there, and the code doesn't seem very idiomatic for Clojure.

The problem is, I don't think I can split that function into smaller parts without doing messy things with global variables and lots of interaction between functions, which will be awful to both implement and debug, if anything goes wrong.

As well as that, some areas of concern:

- is using private functions okay? I'm not sure if that's the Clojure-esque way of doing things.
- I'm not sure if using an atom to change a certain variable is the best way of doing things either.

I've made this into a repository as well, which can be found [here](https://github.com/Qwerp-Derp/beautifier).